Add ip_restriction priorty for azurerm_windows_function_app based off a for_each in terraform
Any idea how to dynamically create priorities based off of a for_each loop for the ip_restriction setting in azurerm_windows_function_app?  I am passing a list of subnet IDs based a subnet data block.
resource "azurerm_windows_function_app" "win-func-app" {
  for_each            = var.func_app
  name                = each.key
  resource_group_name = var.rg1_name
  location            = var.ea2_location

  storage_account_name       = data.azurerm_storage_account.sa.name
  storage_account_access_key = data.azurerm_storage_account.sa.primary_access_key
  service_plan_id            = azurerm_service_plan.asp[each.value.asp].id

  site_config {
    ftps_state          = "FtpsOnly"
    minimum_tls_version = 1.2
    
    application_stack {
      dotnet_version = each.value.dotnet_version
    }
    
    ip_restriction_default_action = "Deny"
   
    dynamic "ip_restriction" {
      for_each = local.vpn
      content {
        ip_address = ip_restriction.value["ip_address"]
        action     = "Allow"
        priority   = ip_restriction.value["priority"]
        name       = ip_restriction.value["name"]
      }
    }
    dynamic "ip_restriction" {
      for_each = data.azurerm_subnet.lt-subnets
      content {
        name = ip_restriction.value.name
        virtual_network_subnet_id = ip_restriction.value.id
        priority   = format("%03d", count.index + 100)
      }
    }
  }

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }


}



Add ip_restriction priorty for azurerm_windows_function_app based off a for_each in terraform

Here is the Terraform code to create IP restriction rules dynamically based on subnet configurations.
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

data "azurerm_subnet" "subnet1" {
  name                 = "vnet"
  virtual_network_name = "venkatvnet"
  resource_group_name  = "VenkatRG"
}

data "azurerm_subnet" "subnet2" {
  name                 = "vnet2"
  virtual_network_name = "venkatvnet"
  resource_group_name  = "VenkatRG"
}

data "azurerm_subnet" "subnet3" {
  name                 = "vnet3"
  virtual_network_name = "venkatvnet"
  resource_group_name  = "VenkatRG"
}

locals {
  subnet_restrictions = [
    for idx, subnet in [
      data.azurerm_subnet.subnet1,
      data.azurerm_subnet.subnet2,
      data.azurerm_subnet.subnet3
    ] : {
      name                      = "subnet-${idx + 1}"
      virtual_network_subnet_id = subnet.id
      priority                  = idx + 100 
    }
  ]
}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name = "VenkatRG"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "venaktstorghjtesttedg1"
  resource_group_name      = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
}

resource "azurerm_service_plan" "example" {
  name                = "example-app-service-plan"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  os_type             = "Windows"
  sku_name            = "Y1"
}
resource "azurerm_windows_function_app" "win_func_app" {
  name                = "venkatapptest1"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location

  storage_account_name       = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
  storage_account_access_key = azurerm_storage_account.example.primary_access_key
  service_plan_id            = azurerm_service_plan.example.id

  site_config {
    ftps_state          = "FtpsOnly"
    minimum_tls_version = 1.2

    ip_restriction_default_action = "Deny"

    dynamic "ip_restriction" {
      for_each = local.subnet_restrictions
      content {
        name                      = ip_restriction.value["name"]
        virtual_network_subnet_id = ip_restriction.value["virtual_network_subnet_id"]
        priority                  = ip_restriction.value["priority"]
        action                    = "Allow" 
      }
    }
  }

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
}

Terraform apply

After running the Terraform code, the IP restrictions rules with dynamic have been created in the networking settings.


I should have been more clear, the issue is more with the priority indexing inside the dynamic block as that looks to only support a for_each.  Was asking to see if there was a way to set that priority inside the dynamic block rather than having a separate locals block.
'dynamic "ip_restriction" {
for_each = data.azurerm_subnet.lt-subnets
content {
name = ip_restriction.value.name
virtual_network_subnet_id = ip_restriction.value.id
priority   = format("%03d", count.index + 100)
}  '

I keep getting invalid index error.
subnet_restrictions = [
for idx, subnet in [data.azurerm_subnet.np-vnet1-subnets] : {
name                      = subnet[idx].name
virtual_network_subnet_id = subnet[idx].id
priority                  = idx + 100
}
]
Error: Invalid index
│
│   on locals.tf line 29, in locals:
│   29:       name                      = subnet[idx].name
│
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value. An object only supports looking up attributes by name, not by numeric index.
